# How to properly delete the char array allocated with a new[] in a char * func()?

Tags: c++, opengl, memory-management, new-operator, delete-operator

This function is reading a textfile into char buffer and returning the pointer to this buffer.

```
char * textfile_to_char(wchar_t *filename)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
    if (FindFirstFile(filename,&data)==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        wchar_t message[256];
        wsprintf(message,L"File could not be found %lp",filename);
        MessageBox(0,message,0,0);
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        HANDLE hFile=CreateFile(filename,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,0,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL|FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY,0);
        if (hFile==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            wchar_t message[256];
            wsprintf(message,L"Error opening file: %lp",filename);
            MessageBox(0,message,0,0);
            return NULL;
        }   
        else
        {
            OVERLAPPED overlapped;
            memset(&overlapped,0,sizeof(overlapped));
            char * buffer=new char[data.nFileSizeLow];
            ReadFileEx(hFile,buffer,data.nFileSizeLow,&overlapped,0);
            CloseHandle(hFile);
            buffer[data.nFileSizeLow]=0;
            return buffer;
        }
    }
}
```

Now here is one more piece of code where I use this function to source openGl shader from this text

```
wchar_t filename[512];
wsprintf(filename,L"%s.vtx",_shader_name);
id_vertex_shader=glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
id_fragment_shader=glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
char *shader_source=textfile_to_char(filename);
char *buffers[2]={shader_source,0};
glShaderSource(id_vertex_shader,1,buffers,0);
delete[] shader_source;
glCompileShader(id_vertex_shader);
```

and delete[] shader_source actually quite confuses me, because a) it doesn't work,b) delete shader_source doesn't work either. So how do i delete it?Thanks

Comment: `buffer[data.nFileSizeLow]=0;` writes beyond the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You do a async read and then expect it to read immediately, and then delete the file handle

add a call to GetOverlappedResult the readFileEx and CloseHandle:

```
ReadFileEx(hFile,buffer,data.nFileSizeLow,&overlapped,0);
WORD bytesRead;
if(!GetOverlappedResult(hFile, &overlapped, &bytesRead, TRUE);){
    //check error and such

}
CloseHandle(hFile);
buffer[bytesRead]=0;
```

or just use ReadFile without the OVERLAPPED struct:

```
WORD bytesRead;
ReadFile(hFile,buffer,data.nFileSizeLow,&bytesRead,0);
CloseHandle(hFile);
```

Comment: If you are going to just wait for the async read you might as well use ReadFile instead of ReadFileEx. Plus not opening file with mode FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED.

Comment: @Smith_61 true I added it in the answer

Comment: Forgot the part where the file isn't being opened with FILE_FLARE_OVERLAPPED in order to call the ReadFileEx method.

Comment: @ratchetfreak If `data.nFileSizeLow == bytesRead`, then index is out of range in `buffer[bytesRead]=0`.